# Accessing polymer events from AngularDart

Tags: dart, polymer, angular-dart

I have successfully gotten AngularDart to detect polymer events using the new on-* and bind-* syntax.

I have the following example where I call a method in my angular component when the "core-select" event is fired:

```
<paper-dropdown valueattr="id" on-core-select="cmp.sendAlert()">
   <paper-item ng-repeat="t in cmp.templates" label="{{t.name}}" id="{{t.id}}">
   </paper-item>
</paper-dropdown>
```

Can I somehow pass in the event object to my method, something like `cmp.sendAlert(event)`? Or just get the selected id passed in somehow? I know I could query the dom from my component, but that doesn't seem like a good way to go about it.

If it matters, I am using the javascript versions of the paper-elements.

regards Oskar

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is `$event` in Angular.dart as far as I remember. Have you tried that?

```dart
<paper-dropdown valueattr="id" on-core-select="cmp.sendAlert($event)">
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I get the following error: `No getter for '$event'.`

Comment: Have you tried `on-core-select="cmp.sendAlert">` and defining like `sendAlert(event) { print(event); }` to verify if it is passed? You can try but honestly I don't expect this to work -> https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/core_dom/event_handler.dart#L59 Maybe you should create a feature request in https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues

Comment: Seems there already exists a pull request to support this https://github.com/vsavkin/angular.dart/blob/add_new_syntax_in_addition_to_on_events/lib/core_dom/event_handler.dart#L60

Comment: That didnt work either, I will look at the linked feature request

Comment: Have you seen my last comment. It seems there already exists a pull request which seems to implement exactly this feature.